# Detect The End Of A Script/Text In Lua

Tags: lua

How can I detect in lua if a user has stop typing in a richtext box/object, so as to enable me compare the current text that has been inputed by the user for further implementations? That is, after the user stops typing a text in the richtext object or box, then the text that has just been typed is compared. However, i have manage to carry-out the further implementation part, like the comparison and the actions to be performed, but my problem is how to detect if the user has stop the typing in the richtext box for the other implementation to follow.

I have tried several approaches, but I am still not getting it right.

Comment: stop typing on *what*? a windows box? a linux box? a mobile phone? a lua terminal? some custom editor?

Comment: @Mike Corcoran: Please i am talking about a richtext object or say richtext box. In this case the user may be typing, but whenever he/she stops typing then the text that has just been typed is compared. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're using a GUI library of some sort to get the richtext box.

What you should look for is a way to see keyboard events. Some GUI toolkits have them. Every time the user presses a key (or there is other input from the keyboard), the OS triggers a Keyboard Event that the program can access. You can use that to tell if the user has entered text. If there is a large pause between events, maybe 2 seconds, you can judge that the user has stopped typing and proceed with the comparisons.

Another way to do it is to look at the contents of the text box. Basically, take a look at contents of the textbox. If they've changed since the last time you've looked, then you should wait a bit and check again. If they haven't changed, assume the user has stopped typing and run your comparison.

Keep in mind that some people type really slowly or may stop to think halfway through typing. This means you can fool yourself if you check too often, and altering the text that the user has just typed *where they can see it* can scare and confuse the user. (Some GUI toolkits remove the text from a textbox when you read all the data, which means the user just saw all their work disappear!) Just be careful.

Honestly, some details on what you're trying to do would be really helpful. As Mike Corcoran indicated, where this script is running can really change what options you have and what options would work best with the program as a whole. For example, a third solution is to simply ask the user to press a button or otherwise indicate that they have finished typing. This isn't a good idea in a text editor, but it would work in some other GUIs.